# Clearing a line of output in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime-format, python-datetime

So, I'm super super new to Python and programming in general. I'm still learning the most basic of commands and terminology. My question is I'm trying to print the datetime in an infinite loop, but only on one line.

I would like the output in the shell to display the date and time and then clear the previously displayed datetime and replace it with the new value. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing, and reading through different questions, I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Any thoughts, help, or guidance would be appreciated. Trying to read the Python Documentation is not helping me at all at this point. This is what I've figured out so far:

```
import datetime
import time

while True:
    today = datetime.date.today()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ("The Current date is ", (today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')))
    print ("The Current Time is ", (now.strftime('%H:%M')))
    time.sleep(30)
```

This Generates:

```
The Current date is  03/28/2017
The Current Time is  19:09
The Current date is  03/28/2017
The Current Time is  19:10
```

I'd like it to say:

```
The Current date is  03/28/2017
The Current Time is  19:09
```

*Then, text above removed and replaced with*

```
The Current date is  03/28/2017
The Current Time is  19:10
```

**Datetime screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It's on a RaspberryPi for those who didn't notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
import datetime
import time
import sys

while True:
    today = datetime.date.today()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ("The Current date is ", (today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')))
    print ("The Current Time is  ", (now.strftime('%H:%M')))
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F") # Cursor up one line
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F") # Cursor up one line
    time.sleep(30)
```

Another option:

import datetime
import time
import os

```
while True:
    today = datetime.date.today()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ("The Current date is ", (today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')))
    print ("The Current Time is ", (now.strftime('%H:%M')))
    time.sleep(30)
    os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Thank you. When I plug this in though, the display produces an output like this:  

``The Current Time is   08:18
[F[FThe Current date is  03/29/2017
The Current Time is   08:19
[F[FThe Current date is  03/29/2017
The Current Time is   08:19
[F[F``

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Good question. I have a raspbian setup and a Windows Setup. I was running off Win7. I didn't think the OS mattered when running within the Pyton Shell. Does it?

Comment: Are you running in python or shell, in terminal or cmd?

Comment: This code works on linux, so if you run it in raspbian it should run correctly.

Comment: running it in Python Shell. I just recreated it in Raspbian. Still giving a similar output only this time with a square next to the letter F.

Comment: You could show me a picture of your execution to understand you better.

Comment: edited the question above with a screen shot of the code running in terminal and running in shell. Python version is 3.6 on windows but 3.4 on Raspbian

Comment: @RL_NooB add new solution

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I was running the script in python 2.7 when I loaded the Terminal. It doesn't work in the Shell, but Terminal works and that's probably what matters.